# $\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4a^2+bc}} \geq \frac{4}{a+b+c}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c \geq 0$ such that $ab+bc+ca>0$. Prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{\sqrt{4a^2+bc}} \geq \frac{4}{a+b+c}$$

I have used the familar one like this: [AOPS solution](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h51089p24385918)

But it is shaper than the old one, can anyone help me please? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Proof.**

By using Holder inequality, we obtain

\begin{align*}
    &\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{4x^2+yz}}\ge}\sqrt{\frac{(2\!\:x+2\!\:y+2\!\:z)^3}{(x+z)^3\!\:(4\!\:y^2+x\!\:z)+(y+z)^3\!\:(4\!\:x^2+y\!\:z)+(x+y)^3\!\:(x\!\:y+4\!\:z^2)}}\ge \frac{4}{x+y+z}\\
    &\Leftrightarrow \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}{\left[ (x-y)^2\left( 40x^2y+40xy^2+72xyz \right) +8z^3(x+y-z)^2 \right]}\ge 0
\end{align*}

I think $pqr$ will helps. I end at this stage.

Equality holds iff $a=b>0,c=0$ and its permutations.